# Unexpected symbol in rabbitmq message and garbage at the end of document

Tags: json, qt, rabbitmq

I am using rabitmq-c library to create a connection and exchange messages in json format between my rabbitmq localhost-server and my client. The received json-object messages in client, I parse with the Qts json support. However If I send a message from server, the client gives strange character at the and of message. And therefore Qtjson can not parse it. I get always "garbage at the end of document" error.

The message, which I send e.g.:

```
{
    "FirstName": "A",
    "LastName": "B",
    "Age": 12,
    "Address": 
     {
        "Street": "abc 10",
        "City": "def",
        "Country": "ghi"
     },
     "Phone numbers": 
     [
       "1234567",
       "2345678"
     ]
}
```

The received message in client:

```
Received message body:
{
  "FirstName": "A",
  "LastName": "B",
  "Age": 12,
  "Address": 
  {
    "Street": "abc 10",
    "City": "def",
    "Country": "ghi"
  },
  "Phone numbers": 
  [
    "1234567",
    "2345678"
  ]
}╬
Size:277
Message Received!
```

Why is the symbol `╬` there?

I receive message with the `amqp_simple_wait_frame` function:

```
// Wait an answer to receive from different queues"
amqp_bytes_free(m_Queue);
{
  amqp_basic_consume(m_Connection, m_Channel, m_Queue, amqp_empty_bytes, m_NoLocal, m_NoAck, m_Exclusive, amqp_empty_table);

  // Reveive message 
  for (;;)
  {
    amqp_maybe_release_buffers(m_Connection);
    m_Result = amqp_simple_wait_frame(m_Connection, &m_Frame);

    m_Deliver = (amqp_basic_deliver_t *)m_Frame.payload.method.decoded;

    printf("m_Delivery: %u \nExchange: %.*s \nRoutingkey/Queue: %.*s \n",
        (unsigned)m_Deliver->delivery_tag, (int)m_Deliver->exchange.len,
        (char *)m_Deliver->exchange.bytes, (int)m_Deliver->routing_key.len,
        (char *)m_Deliver->routing_key.bytes);

    m_Result = amqp_simple_wait_frame(m_Connection, &m_Frame);


    m_Properties = (amqp_basic_properties_t *)m_Frame.payload.properties.decoded;
    if (m_Properties->_flags & AMQP_BASIC_CONTENT_TYPE_FLAG)
    {
        printf("Content-type: %.*s\n", (int)m_Properties->content_type.len, (char *)m_Properties->content_type.bytes);
    }
    std::cout << "----\n" << std::endl;

    m_BodyTarget = (size_t)m_Frame.payload.properties.body_size;
    m_BodyReceived = 0;

    while (m_BodyReceived< m_BodyTarget)
    {
        m_Result = amqp_simple_wait_frame(m_Connection, &m_Frame);

        //m_BodyReceived += m_Frame.payload.body_fragment.len;
        m_BodyReceived = m_Frame.payload.body_fragment.len;
        assert(body_received <= body_target);

        amqp_dump(m_Frame.payload.body_fragment.bytes, m_Frame.payload.body_fragment.len);
        printf("\nReceived message body:%s\nSize:%d\n", m_Frame.payload.body_fragment.bytes, m_Frame.payload.body_fragment.len);
    }


    std::cout << "Message Received! \n\n" << std::endl;

    // Convert received json object to string 
    std::string jsonResponseToString;
    jsonResponseToString = std::string((char*)m_Frame.payload.body_fragment.bytes);

    // Convert string to cpp object
    jsonToCpp(jsonResponseToString);
  }
}
```

And I convert the json-object to the cpp-object as follows:

```
void printArray(QJsonArray array)
{
  for (auto iter = array.begin(); iter != array.end(); ++iter)
  {
    qDebug() << (*iter).toString();
  }
}

void parse(QJsonObject jsonObject)
{
  qDebug() << "Keys";
  for (auto iter = jsonObject.begin(); iter != jsonObject.end(); ++iter)
  {
    qDebug() << iter.key();
  }
  qDebug() << "FirstName " << jsonObject["FirstName"].toString();
  qDebug() << "Phones :";
  printArray(jsonObject["Phone numbers"].toArray());
}

void jsonToCpp(std::string jsonResponseToString)
{

  // std::string to QByteArray
  QByteArray stringToArray(jsonResponseToString.c_str(), jsonResponseToString.length());


  QJsonParseError  parseError;
  QJsonDocument jsonDoc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(stringToArray, &parseError);
  if (parseError.error == QJsonParseError::NoError)
  {
    if (jsonDoc.isObject())
    {
        parse(jsonDoc.object());
    }
  }
  else
  {
    qDebug() << parseError.errorString();
  }
}
```

Here I get the garbage error.

Comment: Is the symbol at the end always the same?

Comment: Yes thats true.

Comment: You might try to remove it bevore `QJsonDocument jsonDoc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(stringToArray, &parseError);`. Also, please share the output of `qDebug() << m_Frame.payload.body_fragment.bytes;`.

Comment: `qDebug() << m_Frame.payload.body_fragment.bytes;` gives only the reference address. What should I remove, the content of received message? Actually with `amqp_bytes_free(m_Queue);` the buffer is removed

Comment: The message in raw format is exactly the same with`The received message in client:` it does not matter, if I parse it or not.

Comment: I might be mistaken, but for me a raw format is a sequence of bytes. May I ask you to show them.

Comment: Earlier I meant to remove the unwanted symbol before the JSON is parsed.

Comment: Since you don't show how you send the message to RabbitMQ, I suggest that you do a traffic capture to see if the extra byte is being inserted prior to the message being sent to RabbitMQ.